# Why can't I update my table with API URL in react-table-v7?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function Items() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios("http://localhost:8080/all")
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}, []);

const columns = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      Header: "Item search",
      columns: [
        {
          Header: "Symbol",
          accessor: "symbol",
          Cell: (props) => (
            <a href={`/history/${props.value}`}>{props.value}</a>
          ),
        },
        {
          Header: "Name",
          accessor: "name"
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
) 

return (
  <div className="Items">
    <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
  </div>
);
}
```

I'm using useTable hook also. I don't get why this code is not working unless I'm missing something else:

```
Cell: (props) => (
            <a href={`/history/${props.value}`}>{props.value}</a>
          ),
```

I want a new table to replace the existing table, once the "symbol" is clicked. But currently all I get is a blank page when I click on symbol.

Comment: don't forget that you have an excellent debugging tool right on the browser, open the dev tool and see what exception was raised.

Comment: There's not a single warning or error in my dev tools, so that's not the issue here

Comment: I may not understand your project but is there a route defined for `'/history/:someValue'` I would imagine if it's loading on first render it means that a route is defined but when it's navigating to a route with params, it's not finding anything resulting in your blank page.